# Matlab chol function returns single number Choleksy decomposition

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, decomposition

I have a matrix `A` which is 390 by 390 and contains numbers such as:

`141270,991258825   -92423,2972762164
-92423,2972762164   60465,8168198016
139998,877391881    -91591,0460330842
30573,0969789307    -20001,7456206658 ...`

If I try `chol(A)`, Matlab fails and says that the matrix must be positive definite. Ok I saw in the API that `[R,p] = chol(A)` also works for negative definite matrices. I tried this, but `R` then becomes a 1x1 matrix. But I expect a 390x390 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help file is slightly unclear here, but it doesn't mean that you can just use a non-positive definite matrix and get the same result by changing the way you call the function:

> [R,p] = chol(A) for positive definite A, produces  an upper triangular
>   matrix R from the diagonal and upper triangle of matrix A, satisfying
>   the equation R'*R=A and p is zero. If A is not positive definite, then
>   p is a positive integer and MATLAB® does not generate an error. When A
>   is full, R is an upper triangular matrix of order q=p-1 such that
>   R'*R=A(1:q,1:q).

If your matrix is not positive definite, p > 0, therefore the size of your result R will depend on `p`.  In fact, I think this particular syntax is simply designed to allow you to use `chol` as a way of checking if A is positive definite, rather than just giving an error if it is not. The help file even says:

> **Note** Using chol is preferable to using eig for determining positive definiteness.

Example - take `pascal(5)` and set the last element to something negative:

```
A =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     3     6    10    15
     1     4    10    20    35
     1     5    15    35    -3
```

`[R,p] = chol(A)` returns

```
R =

     1     1     1     1
     0     1     2     3
     0     0     1     3
     0     0     0     1


p =

     5
```

Sure enough, `R'*R' == A(1:4,1:4)`

By setting element `X(2,2)` to be negative, on the other hand, gives `p` of 2 and therefore a single value in `R` which will be `sqrt(A(1,1)`.  Setting `A(1,1)` to be negative returns `p = 1` and an empty `R`.